# Regex to extract file extension from URL

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regex that would match `.js` in the following URI:

```
 /foo/bar/file.js?cache_key=123
```

I'm writing a function that tries to identify what kind of file is being passed in as a parameter. In this case, the file ends with the extension `.js` and is a javascript file. I'm working with PHP and preg_match so I'm assuming this is a PCRE compatible regular expression. Ultimately I'll build on this expression and be able to check for multiple file types that are being passed in as a URI that isn't just limited to js, but perhaps css, images, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `pathinfo` and a regular expression. `pathinfo` will give you the extension plus the `?cache_key=123`, and you can then remove the `?cache_key=123` with a regex that matches the `?` and everything after it:

```
$url = '/foo/bar/file.js?cache_key=123';

echo preg_replace("#\?.*#", "", pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
js
```

Input:

```
$url = 'my_style.css?cache_key=123';
```

Output:

```
css
```

Obviously, if you need the `.`, it's trivial to add it to the file extension string.

ETA: if you do want a regex solution, this will do the trick:

```
function parseurl($url) {
    # takes the last dot it can find and grabs the text after it
    echo preg_replace("#(.+)?\.(\w+)(\?.+)?#", "$2", $url) . "\n";
}

parseurl('my_style.css');
parseurl('my_style.css?cache=123');
parseurl('/foo/bar/file.js?cache_key=123');
parseurl('/my.dir.name/has/dots/boo.html?cache=123');
```

Output:

```
css
css
js
html
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.+\.(js|css|etc)[?]?
```

extension in $matches[1]

Or you can just use

```
.+\.(js|css|etc)\?
```

if the final ?cache... is always used

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7O3)**

Code

```
$input_line = '/foo/bar/file.js?cache_key=123';

// lets grab the part part between filename and ?
preg_match("/\w+\/\w+\/\w+(.*)\?/", $input_line, $output_array);

var_dump($matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

Output

```
Array
(
   [0] => foo/bar/file.js?
   [1] => .js
)
```

.js

If you know the extensions beforehand (whitelist approach), you might switch from matching everything `(.*)` to matching specific extensions `/.*\.(js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/`

```
preg_match("/.*\.(js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/", $input_line, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // js
```

Comment: This solution is rather dependent upon there being a set number of directories...

Comment: true! structure is /word/word/word(match)? . maybe it's sufficient. who knows. there is always pathinfo().

Comment: You could make the number of directories flexible using `(\/\w+)*` -- matches 0 or more `/\w+`